# JMeter 5.4 - Sending PDF Attachment with SOAP Envelope in 2022

Tags: soap, jmeter

Apologies, but after weeks without success and the only related articles dating back to almost 9 years ago, is there a way that works with JMeter 5.4 to send a SOAP envelope with a PDF attachment?

I have tried the Custom SOAP Sampler plugin approach without much success  apart from stack trace after stack trace and multipart requests using a HTTP Sampler using a SOAP Envelope and boundaries to add content (below - could not get format correct) without success. I have also tried creating the PDF to send using PDFBox but also without success as every time it seems the Content is somehow incorrect.

--A100x

Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Content-ID:

<soapenv:Envelope ....

<inc:Include href="cid:PDF_TO_UPLOAD" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>

.........soapenv:Envelope>

--A100x

Content-Type: text/plain; name=MyDoc.pdf

Content-ID: <PDF_TO_UPLOAD>

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Content-Disposition: attachment; name="My Best Ever Pension Letter"; filename="MyDoc.pdf"

${MY_PDF_CONTENT_VARIABLE}

--A100x--

Can anybody provide a way that works in 2022 with JMeter 5.4 to upload a PDF using using a SOAP envelope please?
(Hopefully not like an Apache bug I came across back in 2012 that said they did not think JMeter was designed for this type of stuff!).

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute the request using your browser or other application like desktop app or a tool like [SoapUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/soapui-load-testing) or [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) - you can just record the request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

Just make sure to copy the PDF file to JMeter's "bin" folder prior to recording, this way JMeter will be able to properly generate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

Also you can find [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/VDqXDNDCr6w) post useful, it's from 2011 but HTTP protocol 1.1 hasn't changed since then so it's still actual.

Comment: As per normal a big thank you Dmitri, I'll follow through them as suggested and advise all.

Comment: The groups.google HTTP Raw Request for SOAP link has a reference to RAW which is dead, so a replacement thread:
https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/CqqBx7vcWc4
And RAW Sampler Usage:
https://dzone.com/articles/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-t
https://dzone.com/articles/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-t

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP envelope is working with the pdf attachment using a plain HTTP Sampler with the multipart boundaries.

The only downside is that whilst the pdf is correctly recognised and stored by the target system whilst a pdf the contnets when viewed are blank.

We are currently using a header to define the Content-Type as per below, but guess it still needs tweaking so the PDF can actually be viewed. (Downloaded pdf's are also blank). And I doubt it is because it is using a white font!

**Content-Type:**   multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start=""; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="AB"